# Numerical Boggle

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

You are probably familiar with the word game [Boggle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle), where you need to construct words by concatenating letters from a grid. Here we will play a numerical version of the game. The rules are as follows:

- Create a 6x6 grid of digits. Each cell must contain a single digit from 0 to 9.
- Starting in one cell you collect digits as you move to neighboring cells (in all 8 directions). As the digits are collected they are concatenated left to right, to form a single number. Note that the starting digit is collected too and you **can** revisit cells.

Your task is to create a 6x6 grid of digits, such that the smallest positive number that cannot be constructed is as large as possible.

Comment: Actually the "Numbers cannot start with a 0" condition is redundant, because it would be never necessary to do so (the leading 0s can be dropped).

Comment: Yes good point! I will remove that condition.

Comment: Great question. I was expecting the answers to quickly hit the 10,000's+, clearly I haven't given it enough thought yet. Is there an invisible no computer tag here? Or may I answer with an algorithmic approach(assuming I can even work one out)?

Comment: You can use computers if you wish - the problem is still difficult.

Comment: Do you collect digits one by one moving in 1 of the 8 directions? Or you somehow move in all 8 directions at the same time?

Comment: When you revisit cells do you add their digits to your number one more time? Or digits disappear from the cells once collected?

Comment: You move one direction at a time. No digits don't disappear and are collected again upon revisit.

Answer (score 16):

> 397

> $\begin{matrix}2&8&8&2&7&5\\6&1&3&7&5&3\\4&3&1&0&4&1\\2&9&5&8&2&4\\0&6&9&2&3&6\\3&0&1&7&6&1\\\end{matrix}$

I used integer linear programming as follows.  Let $C=\{1,\dots,6\}^2$ be the set of cells, and let $D=\{0,\dots,9\}$ be the set of digits.  Let $P=\{(i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2,i_3,j_3)\}$ be the set of paths of length three ($|P|=1460$), and let $T \subseteq \{(d_1,d_2,d_3)\in D^3: d_1 \not= 0\}$ be the set of digit triples to be covered.  (The one- and two-digit numbers will take care of themselves if we cover $100=(1,0,0)$ through $199=(1,9,9)$.)  For $(i,j)\in C$ and $d\in D$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j,d}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ contains digit $d$.  For $p \in P$ and $t\in T$, let binary decision variable $y_{p,t}$ indicate whether path $p$ contains digit triple $t$.  The constraints are:
\begin{align}
\sum_d x_{i,j,d} &= 1 &&\text{for $(i,j)\in C$} \tag1 \\
\sum_p y_{p,t} &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $t$} \tag2 \\
y_{(i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2,i_3,j_3,d_1,d_2,d_3)} &\le x_{i_1,j_1,d_1} 
&&\text{for $(i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2,i_3,j_3)\in P$, $(d_1,d_2,d_3)\in T$} \tag3 \\
y_{(i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2,i_3,j_3,d_1,d_2,d_3)} &\le x_{i_2,j_2,d_2} 
&&\text{for $(i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2,i_3,j_3)\in P$, $(d_1,d_2,d_3)\in T$} \tag4 \\
y_{(i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2,i_3,j_3,d_1,d_2,d_3)} &\le x_{i_3,j_3,d_3} 
&&\text{for $(i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2,i_3,j_3)\in P$, $(d_1,d_2,d_3)\in T$} \tag5
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ forces each cell to contain exactly one digit.
Constraint $(2)$ forces each digit triple to appear at least once.
Constraints $(3)$ through $(5)$ enforce that, if a path contains a digit triple, each cell in the path contains the corresponding digit.

The idea is to take $T$ to be a large set of consecutive numbers starting from $100$ and find a feasible solution.  The one above came from $T=\{(d_1,d_2,d_3)\in D^3: d_1 \not= 0 \land 100d_1+10d_2+d_3 \le 396\}$,
after fixing some of the digits in the 394 solution from @DmitryKamenetsky.

Comment: Great answer! Can you elaborate on your approach?

Comment: I'm using integer linear programming, where the main decisions are represented by binary variables $x_{i,j,k}$ that indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ contains value $k$.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this was the case as ILP is your favorite tool.

Comment: Haha, you always amaze me with your application of ILP in various places RobPratt. Have a +1. Can you describe more what you mean by using binary variables $x_{i,j,k}$ to make decision? Don't we need some sort of sequence in the mix?

Comment: And, most importantly, is this just the best solution you found, or do you have data showing it's the optimal best solution possible?

Comment: I don't know whether this solution is optimal.  I will describe the full ILP formulation later.

Comment: @RobPratt I can confirm that this solution is not optimal.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky, updated just now.

Comment: @RobPratt nice work. Better solutions are still possible.

Comment: @RobPratt so what happens when you change the 338 in the last line to something bigger? Does it just run indefinitely without finding a solution?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Yes.  But I also have some tricks to improve solutions by using modifications of the above formulation.  Have you found something better than 339?

Comment: @RobPratt I see thanks. I have solutions that are better than 339.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky, thanks for the bounty.  Can you please reveal your best solution now?

Comment: Just posted it below. Thanks for participating!

Comment: @RobPratt you should probably mention that you ran your optimisations on my solution to obtain this result, otherwise future users will get confused.

Comment: @RobPratt I have improved the score again, see my update. Perhaps your methods can improve it even further?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I was not able to find any improvement in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:** Here is a new and improved answer of

> 337

As follows

> $\begin{matrix}9&9&2&4&9&6\\1&0&6&5&1&8\\3&4&7&1&5&0\\2&7&4&2&3&0\\1&8&9&3&2&8\\0&5&8&1&6&6\\\end{matrix}$

Comment: ooh nice work! This is getting closer to my solution.

Comment: I'm enjoying watching this puzzling tennis match between you and @RobPratt - just waiting for one of you to smash down an ace to finish the rally!

Comment: @Stiv agree this a great battle of wits. Why don't you join them? ;)

Comment: Are you using the same approach as RobPratt? If not, what is yours?

Answer (score 7):

I have found

> 394

with this grid

> $\begin{matrix}2&8&0&2&7&3\\6&1&3&9&8&7\\6&3&1&5&9&1\\2&4&7&6&2&4\\4&5&0&2&3&8\\5&3&1&0&8&1\\\end{matrix}$

I used a hill climbing algorithm that changes one value at a time. It accepts a move if it increases (or equals) the score, otherwise it rejects it. After all possible changes have been tried, it adds some random mutations and restarts the process. I ran multiple processes of this method for about a week and it only found this grid once. Hence I am not convinced that this solution is optimal.

It was a fun problem and I thank everyone for participating. I got the idea from [this competition](http://www.v-sonline.com/index.pl?C6) and I encourage you to check it out.

**UPDATE:**

I have improved my algorithm and was able to get a higher score of

> 399

with this grid

> $\begin{matrix}0&5&1&1&9&9\\5&0&3&6&2&8\\2&9&4&2&0&8\\7&1&5&7&1&3\\7&3&6&8&3&1\\3&6&9&2&4&4\\\end{matrix}$

> Note if we can make 399, then we will also get 400 to 405 for free.

Comment: I was able to improve this by 1 just now.

Comment: Wow cool! Your solution looks quite different though. I am guessing you initialized your variables with my solution first and then ran your optimization?

Comment: Yes, one of my improvement heuristics for a given solution is to fix all occurrences of a subset of digits and optimize the rest.

Answer (score 5):

As of now I have:

> 168

> [image]

I may be able to squeeze a few more

Comment: @daw start from one of the central 1s, go to an adjacent central 0, go diagonally to the other adjacent central 0.

Answer (score 4):

No guarantees of optimality, but I'll start us off with a score of

> $117:$
>  $\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1&2&0\\3&4&5&3&6&7\\7&8&9&6&4&4\\1&9&0&2&8&8\\3&0&2&5&6&0\\3&4&5&7&7&1\end{matrix}$

Comment: Great start to the problem

Comment: Nice. I have checked that your score is correct.